# How to unmix a known combination of signals to obtain principal components?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, matlab

I am working on Principal Component Analysis as part of my project.
I am constructing 3 sinusoidal signals with white Gaussian noise added to it and creating 3 more signals by linear combination of the constructed signals.
I have to use Matlab PCA command to and need to unmix the signals and remove the noise.

Kindly please provide an example or any reference code to unmix the combined signals using Matlab PCA command.

Comment: PCA is not designed for "unmixing" but rather to detect principal modes of variation; "unmixing-like" result can appear if the original sources are orthogonal to each other. What you described appears to be a classical example of BBS/ICA (Blind Signal Seperation / Independent Component Analysis). Also if you are explore sinusoidals etc. just FFT/DCT the thing, that is what it is for!

Comment: This question is so focused on Matlab that it makes me think it is rather off-topic here.